# CarrierWave Stub Request Error "Not allowed to upload application/octet-stream files"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rspec

In a Rails app, I'm writing an RSpec test for an upload method that inherits functionality from CarrierWave. The method itself looks at the URL of a user uploaded image, downloads it, and re-uploads it to S3. In testing, the final step uploads to local storage instead of S3.

I'm trying to modify this process with a stub request. When CarrierWave requests the URL, I intercept with the stub, tell it to return a local file instead.

That part works.

The error comes when CarrierWave tries to upload the stubbed file.This is the error.

```
CarrierWave::IntegrityError: You are not allowed to upload application/octet-stream files
```

Here is the stub request.

```
## rails_helper.rb

...

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'webmock/rspec'

...

RSpec.configure do |config|

  ...

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    body_file = File.open(File.expand_path('./spec/fixtures/files/1976.png'))
    stub_request(:get, /fakeimagehost.com/).to_return(status: 200, body: body_file)
```

Here is the RSpec

```
...
context 'when uploaded image URL does not match AWS URL' do
  let(:image) { build(:user_uploaded_image) }
  let(:image_file) { 'spec/fixtures/files/1976.png' }
  let(:html_string) { "<img src='http://fakeimagehost.com/image.png'" }
  let(:upload_foreign_image_service) { UploadForeignImageService.new(html_string) }

  it 'returns an array of uploaded images' do
    expect(upload_foreign_image_service.upload_images).to eql([image])
  end
end
...
```

Here is the relevant portion of the upload method.

```
...    
@uploaded_images = []

def upload_images
  parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(@original_html)
  parsed_html.css('img').each do |element|
    source = element.attributes['src'].value
    if source.match ...
      ...
      @uploaded_images |= [existing_image] if existing_image.present?
    else
      new_image = UserUploadedImage.new
      #### BLOWS UP HERE  ####
      new_image.embedded_image.download! source

      ...

    end
  end
  @uploaded_images
end
```

Happy to provide the `UserUploadedImage` class as well.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem. In the `.to_return` portion of the stub request, I needed to specify the file type.

```
stub_request(:get, /fakeimagehost.com/).to_return(status: 200, body: body_file, headers: {'Content-Type' =>'image/png'}
```

This `headers: {'Content-Type' =>'image/png'}` was the missing piece.